# when users clicks on the community site members, it will redirect to different destination

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, community

I have a community site inside SharePoint server 2013.and under the members section for the community site, if a user clicks on a member image, he will be redirected to either:-

1. "People and Groups : User Information", Page

OR

2. he will be redirected to the member personal page the URL will look as `/my/Person.aspx?accountname=`

So I have the following two questions:-

1. why SharePoint will redirect to different places? is this because some users have personal sites , while other does not ?
2. To avoid the inconsistency redirection for end users, is there a way to make the usernames un-clickable, so no redirect will happen when a user clicks on any member ? but keep the Lync server integration active?.

The members links which i need to make them UN-clickakble are:-
[image]

**Edit**

My script looks as follow:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ms-acal-apanel-title span").text('Select Calendar/s');
 $(".ms-subtleLink").removeAttr('href');
$(".ms-subtleLink").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

the first statement works well , but the second two statements will not work. and this proof that i am not having problem with my jquery, because the first statement changed the title correctly,,, what do u think ?

Comment: One thing you can test is to open a Google Chrome console with F12 key and put this code var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();  
Then paste the code of document.ready including document.ready itself and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiet so, the reason is because the user has no mysite created.

Once again, The only way I can imagine right now is JQuery approach.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-subtleLink").removeAttr('href');
    $(".ms-subtleLink").removeAttr('onclick');});
```

Comment: not sure why ,, but also this did not work !!

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work for you. You have something wrong with your JQuery configuration because it really works in my environment and my customer's. Add my code to document.ready. I edited the code

Comment: i added it to a separate script and it worked well

Comment: but is there a way to apply Jquery hover setting so that then the user hover over the username it chnage the background color ?

Comment: sure there it is but I would have to do a proof of concept